# Transition for a Collapse

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm working on a custom collapser but I don't know how I can make a transition when hiding. 
Searching online I found "display: none;", but it doesn't support transition. 
I've tried to do height: auto; and then height: 0px; but it doesn't support transition too.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<a class="clp" href="#clp-1"><div>Button</div></a>
<div class="clp-body clp-show" id="clp-1">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

CSS

```
 .clp > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.clp {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: black;
}

.clp-body {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.clp-show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.clp-show {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none; /* Only for the example */
}
```

JS (jQuery)

```
 $('a.clp').click(function(){
  var value = $(this).attr("href");
  if ($('div'+(value)).hasClass('clp-show')) {
    $('div'+(value)).addClass('clp-hide');
    $('div'+(value)).removeClass('clp-show');
  }
  else {
    $('div'+(value)).removeClass('clp-hide');
    $('div'+(value)).addClass('clp-show');
  };
});
```

Here's a link: https://codepen.io/Keyon/pen/937706ce73bc3f68cbeff6dd6faf6c87

Comment: What type of transition do you want? You might be looking for jQuery's slideUp() and slideDown() functions. Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/).

Comment: @JosephBeard I've already tried it too, but it has a strange behavior [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Keyon/pen/14b311941ee4b2e3973bcc6acd5949ee)

Comment: It looks like the odd behavior is caused by using the CSS transition together with slideUp or slideDown. If you remove `transition: all 0.5s ease;` from your CSS, the sliding works properly.

Comment: @JosephBeard Ok perfect, thank you! :)

Comment: @JosephBeard Add your comment as answer so I can mark it as valid solution

Comment: Just added my comments as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) and [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) and to expand and collapse your div like this:

```
$('#clp-1').slideDown(); // expand
$('#clp-1').slideUp(); // collapse
```

You'll also need to remove the CSS line `transition: all 0.5s ease;` for the jQuery sliding to work properly.

Comment: When will you `slideUp()` & `slideDown()`? Check my answer, it will give you most ideal way to acheive your behavior. If you really want to go the jQuery way, then use `$.toggle()` instead of `slideUp()` & `slideDown()` separately. Ideal is to toggle the class and transition using CSS

Answer (score 4):

Why not use Jquery's Fade or Slide animations, you can make your own with the animate function.

Fade:

```
 $('div'+(value)).fadeIn();
 $('div'+(value)).fadeOut();
```

Slide:

```
 $('div'+(value)).slideUp();
 $('div'+(value)).slideDown();
```

To create your own animation:

```
  $('div' + (value)).animate({
      //some css propeties example:
      margin-right: 500px
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Transition does not work on height, you need to use max-height. Use the below CSS.

```
.clp-body {
    max-height: 0; /* set the initial height to 0 */
    transition: max-height .5s ease-in; /* define the transition */
}
.clp-show {
    max-height: 1000px; /* set it to some high value but it will not expand more than the content height */
}
```

Toggle the `clp-show` class on click of the `.clp`

```
$(".clp").on("click", function () {
    $(".clp-body").toggleClass("clp-show");
});
```

EDIT:
You will not need `display:none` as we are setting the `max-height: 0` initially

Answer (score 1):

You can animate the css properties using jQuery.

```
$('a.clp').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr("href");
    var targetDiv = $('div' + (value));
    targetDiv.toggleClass('clp-show');
    if (targetDiv.hasClass('clp-show')) {
       targetDiv.css('display', 'block');
       targetDiv.animate({
         opacity: 1
       }, 500);

    } else {
       targetDiv.animate({
         opacity: 0
       }, 500, function() {
         // This will be executed when the animation is complete
         targetDiv.css('display', 'none');
       });
    }
});
```

Here's an updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/tuncelmert/pen/evwYWJ). I made some alterations to the CSS too. This way we make sure it's animated nicely and then be gone when the transition is complete. Otherwise it may block some mouse events and affect other elements.

**UPDATE**

Here's the jQuery for collapsing ([codepen](http://codepen.io/tuncelmert/pen/evwmzG)):

```
$('a.clp').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr("href");
    var targetDiv = $('div' + (value));
    targetDiv.toggleClass('clp-show');
    targetDiv.slideToggle(500);
});
```

You don't need class toggling here but I left it in case you want to change other CSS properties.

Comment: Ok that's good, but do you know how to use a "collapse animation"?
Instead of using opacity, use something like height.

Comment: Also, please take css changes in the codepen into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

**Use these classes properties may be it's work**

```css
.clp-show {
  opacity: 1;
  height:auto;
  overflow:visible;
}

.clp-show {
  opacity: 0;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS animation on the `height` property.

```
div #hidingDiv {
    height: 50px
    width: 50px
}
@keyframes shrinkup {
    from {
        height: 50px
    }
    to {
        height: 0px
    }
```

When you want it to disappear:

```
document.getElementById("hidingDiv").setAttribute("style", "animation-name: shrinkup; animation-duration: 5s")
```

This simply sets the animation on the `div` when you run the JavaScript code.

Comment: I don't want to use a static height, that's the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

```
.slideToggle()
```

It combines : `.toggle()` + `.slideUp()` + `.slideDown()`